# Add New columns in Html Table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have created one HTML table using a `forEach` loop.

I need to add one column in the only header portion.

I have two titles which are display in two tables simultaneously, Open Projects and Closed Projects, and I need to add columns under both of them.

[image: screenshot of my application]

```html
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%;" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table style="width:100%;">
        @foreach ($boardgroups as $boardgroupsitem)
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h2>{{$boardgroupsitem["grouptitle"]}}</h2>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tbl_table">
              <tbody>
                <tr id="tr_Col">
                  <td style="width:220px;font-weight:bold;"></td>
                  @php $i=0; foreach($group as $subgroup) { @endphp

                  <td style="width:180px;text-align:center;">
                    {{$subgroup[$i]->title}}
                  </td>
                  @php $i++; } @endphp
                </tr>
              </tbody>
              <tr id="tr_row">
                <td></td>
                @php $i=0; $mainid=$boardgroupsitem["id"]; $i=0; foreach($grouprows[$mainid] as $grouprw) { $i++; @endphp
                <td id="div_row" style="text-align:center;">{{$grouprw["title"]}}</td>
                @php if($i%2==0) { @endphp

              </tr>
              <td></td>
              @php } } @endphp
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Share your code as snippet.

Comment: I can give you an example for your reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/q9fvbr4e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to add new column to the table with the id `tbl_table`. If so, maybe this will work in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnAddColumn").on('click', function(){
        $("#tbl_table tr").append("<td></td>");
    });  
});
```

What we are doing is, we are adding empty `<td>` elements to each row of the table with the id `tbl_table` when a button with the id `btnAddColumn` is clicked.

Also, I would like to point out some things.

- You can enclose all the `<tr>` elements inside the `<tbody>`. A table can have a `<thead>` and a `<tbody>`.
- Secondly, when you use `id=` attribute for any elements, make sure that you are not repeating the same id. I mean, the `id` attribute should be unique in a HTML dom. That is, no two elements can have the same `id` name! In your code, I believe you are repeating the ids `tr_row`, `div_row`, `tr_Col`, `tbl_table`, etc. as these are inside a loop! In such cases, a `class` attribute is the best. Because `class` names are not expected to be unique, whereas `id` names are!

Hope it helps. If not, please EDIT your question and include more details so that we maybe able to throw some more ideas.

---

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, am providing the solution.

Try changing this line:

```
<tr id="tr_Col">
```

to

```
<tr class="tr_Col">
```

Then, try this code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnAddColumn").on('click', function(){
        $(".tr_Col").append("<td></td>");
    });  
});
```

Comment: I have checked with  $('#tbl_table tbody tr:first ').append("<td class='TableHeading'>second</td>");.through this i am getting only one column for my first title.i need the same for second title .for these title  i m using only one tr..

Comment: Because you are using this in your selector query: `tr:first`. This means only the first `<tr>` element is considered. So only the first `<tr>` element in your table with the id `tbl_table` gets the new column appended! If you want to consider the other rows in the same table, simply remove `:first` in your the selector.

Comment: Then it will applicable for all tr.I don't want like that i need to display in header columns.Along with title it should come.but i am displaying that title is one by one

Comment: Am not sure which all are your header columns! If you can give us a screenshot of the code and mark the locations where you wanted the columns to be appended, maybe we would be able to help you.

Comment: Already i uploaded my screen shot.just check it.there i have two titles under that two columns each.when i press one but i need to add one columns for each title.only columns i have to add  column after the owner columns for each title.only columns i have to add

Comment: Yes i need like that

Comment: Am sorry. I can't give any new inputs unless I get a clear idea. Can you just copy paste the rendered html? Means, the one from your browser, which doesn't have the php codes. Post that code here: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I made some correction in my coding and its working now.Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to know that its resolved! I would suggest posting your solution(as a new ANSWER and accept that answer by clicking on the checkbox near to it). In that way, it would help others who are facing similar issues.

Comment: Its working fine.now i added my column i need to add rows under that column.How is possible?